# Was Keith ever charged with murder?

Tags: 24

In season 1 of *24*, a lot of attention is devoted to events that were covered up in Senator Palmer's family, specifically that his son Keith was involved in the death of Lyle Gibson.

I'm currently watching season 2 and the question has not been answered yet. Even though it's over a year later, Keith appears only briefly in this season and there's a reference that the (now) President has made the right decision by telling the truth, but it's not clear if Keith was ever charged for anything.

Was Keith ever charged with murder for the events during and prior to season 1?